# How to use Range.find with date?

Tags: excel, vba, date, find, range

I'm using the find-method on a range of cells (one row) with dates.

That seems to be the relevant part of my code:

```
Dim ws_gantt As Worksheet
Dim letztezeile_gantt As Long
Dim zeile_gantt As Integer
Dim spalte_gantt As Integer
Dim date_ed As Date
Dim suchString As String
Dim suchRange As Range

[...]
        letztezeile_gantt = ws_gantt.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For zeile_gantt = 4 To letztezeile_gantt Step 2
            date_ed = ws_gantt.Cells(zeile_gantt, 300).Value

            Set suchRange = ws_gantt.Rows(3).Find(date_ed, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=True)
            If Not suchRange Is Nothing Then
                ws_gantt.Cells(zeile_gantt, suchRange.Column).Value = "."
            End If
            
            [...]
        Next
[...]
```

I tried some variations, but my "suchRange" is always Nothing, even if the date to find is in row 3.

E.g. I used a different range definition, CDbl(date_ed), CLng(date_ed), CDbl(CDate(date_ed)), CStr(date_ed), ... but always: "Nothing".

How do I use the `.find` method on dates? I use the "German" Dateformat (DD/MM/YYY).

Comment: If you just loop over the search range are you able to match the search value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xlFormulas

```
Set suchRange = ws_gantt.Rows(3).Find(date_ed, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=True)
```

to

```
Set suchRange = ws_gantt.Rows(3).Find(date_ed, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True)
```

The value that appears in the cell is xlvalues. Therefore, if a cell is given a different format, the value is recognized as different.

In the example below, different cell formats are applied, but each expression has the same value, so it is recognized as the same.

```
Sub test()
    Dim date_ed As Date
    Dim ws_gantt As Worksheet
    Dim suchRange  As Range
    Dim myday As Long
    Dim newDay As Date
    Dim rng As Range, rngDB As Range
    
    Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone
    
    Set ws_gantt = ActiveSheet
    Set rngDB = ws_gantt.Range("a3", "a6")
    
    date_ed = #6/23/2020#
    
    For Each rng In rngDB
        Set suchRange = rng.Find(date_ed, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=True)
        suchRange.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    Next rng

    
End Sub
```

### Same data Image

[image]